# web.config is replaced with default in DevOps drop

Tags: asp.net-core, azure-devops, azure-pipelines

ASP.NET Core 3.1 project uses the following line in `csproj` to copy a customized `web.config` from the `wwwroot` folder into the output folder:

```
<ItemGroup>
  <Content Update="wwwroot\Web.config" CopyToOutputDirectory="Always" CopyToPublishDirectory="Always" Link="%(Filename)%(Extension)" />
</ItemGroup>
```

The project is compiled using Azure DevOps classic (non-YAML) pipeline:

- .NET Core task (Task version 2.0), command `restore`
- .NET Core task (Task version 2.0), command `build`
- .NET Core task (Task version 2.0), command `publish` with [x] Publish web projects, [x] Zip published projects and [x] Add project's folder name to publish path
- Publish build artifacts task (Task version 1.0)

Builds up to July 2020 retained the customized `web.config` in the build artifact as expected, just with the following lines being **injected** to the customized `web.config`:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<configuration>
  <system.webServer>
    <...>our custom settings defaultDocument, staticContent, rewrite and rewriteMaps</...>
    <handlers>
      <add name="aspNetCore" path="*" verb="*" modules="AspNetCoreModuleV2" 
resourceType="Unspecified" />
    </handlers>
    <aspNetCore processPath="dotnet" arguments=".\Something.dll" stdoutLogEnabled="false" stdoutLogFile=".\logs\stdout" hostingModel="inprocess" />
  </system.webServer>
</configuration>
<!--ProjectGuid: SOME-GUID -->
```

But the builds made yesterday and today contains different `web.config`, **missing** the customized parts while adding a `<location>` tag:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<configuration>
  <location path="." inheritInChildApplications="false">
    <system.webServer>
      <handlers>
        <add name="aspNetCore" path="*" verb="*" modules="AspNetCoreModuleV2" resourceType="Unspecified" />
      </handlers>
      <aspNetCore processPath="dotnet" arguments=".\Something.dll" stdoutLogEnabled="false" stdoutLogFile=".\logs\stdout" hostingModel="inprocess" />
    </system.webServer>
  </location>
</configuration>
<!--ProjectGuid: SOME-GUID -->
```

Note: There were no builds between July and yesterday. The only change made in the project source was just a few unrelated minor text changes in Razor views. The pipeline definition is kept unchanged for at least a year.

July's build agent logged these versions:

```
Current agent version: '2.171.1'
Current image version: '20200630.0'
Downloading task: DotNetCoreCLI (2.171.3)
Downloading task: PublishBuildArtifacts (1.158.3)
```

November's build agent logged these versions:

```
Current agent version: '2.177.1'
Included Software: https://github.com/actions/virtual-environments/blob/win19/20201116.1/images/win/Windows2019-Readme.md
Current image version: '20201116.1'
Downloading task: DotNetCoreCLI (2.175.0)
Downloading task: PublishBuildArtifacts (1.158.3)
```

Why the web.config in the artifacts no longer contains the customized part? How to fix it?

Comment: The two web.configs you listed are identical.

Comment: Yes, the cited parts are identical. The difference is that in July, this part was **injected** into our web.config from webroot, while in November, this part **replaced** our web.config completely.

Comment: What's the result if you build locally? I would suggest you give a try to rollback to the old agent version.  You could find the agent in our official Github link: https://github.com/microsoft/azure-pipelines-agent/releases/tag/v2.171.1

Comment: Still the same. I can't downgrade as we're using the Microsoft-provided Hosted Agents windows-2019 pool, not Self-hosted agents.